# add product into cart

Tags: product, cart, addtocart

I created an **"add to cart button"** for a product at below location.

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Now I want while **clicking** on the **button**, the **product**,  should go into **"cart"**. How can I do it? I am very new in **Magento developer**.So, please explain step by step, and  also suggest me a better **website and book for  developement**.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml.

```
<?php $cart_url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>
<a href="<?php echo $cart_url;?>" >Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look into **addtocart.phtml** file in:

```
default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

This file has the Add to cart button.

Answer (score 0):

i created "add to cart" button in below images 
/var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
now i want while i clicking , product should add into "cart" how i can do please guide me step be step [image]